# Xamarin Debugger won't attach to iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When trying to debug on device using profile "Debug|iPhone > Casey's iPad" xamarin first shows this at the top:

[image: Waiting for debugger to connect to Casey's iPad on port 10000 via USB...]

Then it launches the app, show the splashscreen, and immediately crashes.  About a minute later I get this popup:

[image: Could not connect to the debugger]

Debugging on the simulator works fine, and debugging on device in Xcode works, I just cannot debug on device in Xamarin.

I've tried the following things with no luck:

1. [Installed latest version of Xcode command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21409806/2301021)
2. Build an objective-c hello world app in xcode, launch and debug on both device and simulator hoping Xcode would ["wave the magic wand"](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/49337/#Comment_49337)
3. Creating a new HelloWorld app and trying to debug it on device - the same thing happens
4. Changing my USB port number to 10001
5. [Changed TestFlight code to only run if !DEBUG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17178613/2301021)
6. [Changed my signing identity from Developer (Automatic) to my specific developer certificate](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/25716/#Comment_25716)

I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.10 and Xcode 7.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.11.1.
I've tried just about anything I could find on Google and had no luck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the device registered on the apple developer portal? Are you using the correct provisioning profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to do the following 2 things:

1. Actually define the DEBUG symbol in the Project Options -> Compiler -> Define Symbols. I was using !DEBUG in my code but it wasn't ever defines. Once I did this the debugger would attach but breakpoints still were not being hit.
2. Set Project Options -> Compiler -> Debug Information = full for all referenced libraries.  Even though my main project had this set I still needed to set it for the referenced libs.

Answer (score 0):

Simply launching the app manually while the debugger is waiting fixed the problem.

I got this help from this page: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/24010/#Comment_24010